# Python executable console not showing up

Tags: python, json, pyinstaller, executable

My python project has both a `main.py` and `key.json`. When I use pyinstaller to download `main.py` as a single executable, the console flashes and closes immediately. How do I fix this? Is anyone else having the same problem?

Here is `main.py`:

```
import random
import json
import os
file_path = 'key.json'
char = 0
letters = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%&*?+-')
#key = assign randomized 2-3 characters to each letter
print('Want a new encryption key? Type "New_Key"')
#startup check if key.json is empty
if os.stat(file_path).st_size == 0:
    key = []
    while char < len(letters):
        rand = random.randint(0, len(letters) - 1)
        key.append(letters[rand])
        char = char + 1
    char = 0
    while char < len(letters):
        rand = random.randint(0, len(letters) - 1)
        key[char] = key[char] + letters[rand]
        char = char + 1
    char = 0
    while char < len(letters):
        rand = random.randint(1, 2)
        if rand == 2:
            rand = random.randint(0, len(letters) - 1)
            key[char] = key[char] + letters[rand]
            if char > 0:
                key[char] = " " + key[char]
            char = char + 1
        else:
            if char > 0:
                key[char] = " " + key[char]
            char = char + 1
    key = "".join(key)
    jsonFile = open("key.json", "w")
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(key))
    jsonFile.close()
    # convert key.json contents to usable list
    with open("key.json") as f:
        key = [key.rstrip() for key in f]
    key = ''.join(map(str, key)).replace('"', "")
    key = key.split()
#Input password for encryption
#The input “New_Key” creates a new encryption key in key.json
repeat = 0
while repeat < 1:
    inp = input('Enter: ')
    if inp == "New_Key":
        char = 0
        open("key.json", "w").close()
        key = []
        while char < len(letters):
            rand = random.randint(0, len(letters) - 1)
            key.append(letters[rand])
            char = char + 1
        char = 0
        while char < len(letters):
            rand = random.randint(0, len(letters) - 1)
            key[char] = key[char] + letters[rand]
            char = char + 1
        char = 0
        while char < len(letters):
            rand = random.randint(1, 2)
            if rand == 2:
                rand = random.randint(0, len(letters) - 1)
                key[char] = key[char] + letters[rand]
                if char > 0:
                    key[char] = " " + key[char]
                char = char + 1
            else:
                if char > 0:
                    key[char] = " " + key[char]
                char = char + 1
        key = "".join(key)
        jsonFile = open("key.json", "w")
        jsonFile.write(json.dumps(key))
        jsonFile.close()
        # convert key.json contents to usable list
        with open("key.json") as f:
            key = [key.rstrip() for key in f]
        key = ''.join(map(str, key)).replace('"', "")
        key = key.split()
    else:
        inp_num = 0
        output = []
        # convert key.json contents to usable list
        with open("key.json") as f:
            key = [key.rstrip() for key in f]
        key = ''.join(map(str, key)).replace('"', "")
        key = key.split()
        while inp_num < len(inp):
            list_num = 0
            while list_num < len(letters):
                if inp[inp_num] == letters[list_num]:
                    output.append(key[list_num])
                    list_num = list_num + 1
                else:
                    list_num = list_num + 1
            inp_num = inp_num + 1
        output = "".join(output)
        print(output)
```

Note: `main.py` works and the console shows up. I think it might have something to do when main.py converts to an executable. It may be due to the startup not being able to function due to `key.json` not being compiled in the executable.

Comment: How are you running pyinstaller?  What does main.py do?

Comment: ```main.py``` creates a random key as a list and puts it in the ```file.json```. It accesses the list in ```file.json``` as a “memory”. ```main.py``` needs ```file.json``` to work.

Comment: So the script runs and then exits. What are you expecting it to do differently?

Comment: The script is a password encryptor and prints an input area for your password to be encrypted. That requires the console. I can’t use it if the console doesn’t show up.

Comment: How do I get the console to stay up?

Comment: To be able to say more we'd have to see `main.py` or a more minimal version thereof. You could even try one that just has an `input()` call. Chances are there's also an error in your code causing it to just exit with a traceback (you can check the return code)

Comment: This is a few snippets on what makes ```main.py``` work. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an 'input' function to wait for the user to input the password.

```
pwd = input("Enter New Password: ")
```

And then use the value in the pwd variable to encrypt.

**Update:**

One way to debug exe from pyinstaller would be to execute it from command line. You can try that. Your latest code works when I have a key.json in the same folder as the exe. As you are writing keys into key.json, you'll need to have the file there.

From command line:

[image]

Directy Executing Exe:

[image]

Comment: I already have a variable like that called ```inp```. It is listed as ```inp = input(‘Enter: ‘)``` which lies in a forever loop. What else could be causing the problem?